# profile name not valid when creating SQL server 2014 availability group

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, availability-groups

I tried creating an availability group but keep encountering this error during the validation checks

> Create failed for Database 'HADR Seeding Test
>   2d074a6f-c035-4046-ae4e-045436ca56c5'.
>
> An exception occurred while executing a Transact-SQL statement or
>   batch. (Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo)
>
> profile name is not valid (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 14607)

Comment: Is it possible that on the secondary replica that you are trying to add, that you have a `TRIGGER` on any `CREATE DATABASE` statement that is set to send an email? If it attempts to send an email and uses an incorrect profile you could receive this message.

Comment: Besides what @Nic mentioned, if you are wondering what this database is about, read this: https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/jonathan/the-availability-group-wizard-and-the-hadr-seeding-test-database/

Comment: Thanks @Nic... The profile name being used to send emails in the CREATE DATABASE trigger was incorrect. I fixed that and everything's fine now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Nic rightly suggested, the secondary replica had a trigger to send emails on CREATE DATABASE statements which was set to use an incorrect profile name. I corrected that and validation checks completed successfully.